# How to create a kernel mode keyboard hook for modifying input

Tags: kernel, hook

I've made a user mode keyboard hook in windows modifying input.

Right now I got my eyes on making a kernel hook for the exactly same task, which by the looks of my last hour of 2 of search is not easy task, at least not as easy as the user one.

So after looking for it I couldn't find any real "hands into" guide to begin the learning experience and now I'm kinda lost on what to do now.

Also if you know resources or practical guides over this process I would greatly appreciate you sharing them with me.